# Which one runs first: @AfterTest or @TestListener?

Tags: java, unit-testing, annotations, automated-tests, testng

I have a TestNG program that creates files as part of the test but those files need to be deleted after the test runs. So I will use an `@AfterTest` anotation to do this.
The problem is that my `TestListener` uses these files to generate error reports after every failed test.

Which one runs first, the `@AfterTest` annotation or the attached `Listener`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a simple test application to find the answer you desire. In pseudocode:

```
someTest() { print "Test was run." }

@AfterTest
afterTest() { print "AfterTest method was run." }

@TestListener
testListener() { print "TestListener method was run." }
```

Build this and run it; that should help you answer your question.